# What would be the originating hostname if an external api is called from Parse Cloud?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I've tried myappname.parseapp.com and parse.com without any luck. I need to call a 3rd party api where I need to provide a whitelist of domains. I am calling the api using Parse.Cloud.HttpRequest()

Answer (score 0):

There is no complete list of the hostnames you might see as the origin of a request so there is no real answer unfortunately.

You can do the following however: write a Cloud Code function that sends an HTTP request to a script on your server (one that does not require whitelisting obviously) and log the hostname the request is coming from. Then look at that list and search for patterns (in case the whitelisting logic of the 3rd party service allows for something like *.somedomain.com)

Comment: Tried it but the host name actually prints the name of the server I'm sending the request to. I've written a small express app and have been able to find an ip and port using req.socket.remoteAddress and req.socket.remotePort. But no luck with the domain name. Any idea on how to get the domain name?

Comment: In PHP there is the `gethostbyaddr` function you can use to (try to) convert an IP to the hostname. Maybe give this a shot? http://php.net/gethostbyaddr

Comment: I've found the domain by using a separate service and seems like Parse is using Amazon AWS for Cloud Code. And it's very much possible that they are using multiple nodes, so it's not possible to add them to the whitelist even if I can get the host names dynamically. Seems to me, the only way is to do the api call from another server which has a static domain and using Parse Hook to forward the call there. I'll test it out.